# necessary observation inputs for local costmap generation

Tags: navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, All,

in the costmap parameter definition below, are both inputs, laser and point cloud, needed?

```
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor point_cloud_sensor
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_laser, data_type: PointCloud, topic: point_cloud, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

can I have only one? say  laser_scan_sensor?

thanks
ray

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190542/necessary-observation-inputs-for-local-costmap-generation/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can. Does something with having only one not work?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0